# how to get filename in folder with order

Tags: php

I have a one core php file in which i want to get file name in a particular folder with order like,
I have many files but each file name like filename_0,filename_1,filename_2 like this so when ever i fetch file name in folder that is not proper order and i am getting filename_0,filename_2,filename_1..

```
    $dir_path="/var/lib/myproject";
        $folder=dir("$dir_path");
                    $j=0;$allfilename='';
                    while($folderEntry=$folder->read())
                    {
                        if($folderEntry == '.' || $folderEntry == '..' )
                        {
                        continue;
                        }else{
echo "Path of directory is>>>>>>>>".$folderEntry;
                        $allfilename[]=$folderEntry;
                        $j++;
                        }
                    }
  $folder->close();
```

i can fetch file name but not getting order so any order loke incremented filename_0 to continue file name .....
so can any one any idea how to get file name with ascending order.

Comment: Can't you load all filenames and sort them? http://php.net/manual/en/function.sort.php

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can always [natsort](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sort.php) the filename array.

```
natsort($allfilename);
```

Note here natural sort is necessary as you might want to consider `filename_1` is before `filename_100`. Another option is using [sort](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sort.php) function.

```
sort($allfilename, SORT_NATURAL);
```

Comment: if i am using second parameter "SORT_NATURAL" then what happen ?

Comment: @BhavikPatel I think you got the answer already. But for reference, `SORT_NATURAL` sorts in natural order. Its same as `natsort`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `sort()` to order the array values, (I mean it will sort the file names in the array)

```
sort($allfilename);
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.sort.php

**UPDATE:**

If you want to preserve index then use `asort`

[asort](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.asort.php) - Sort an array and maintain index association

```
asort($allfilename);
```

Comment: if i am using sort function then getting proper result but i want to update their index also like my first array and afer sort array but index is also not updated

Comment: you want to preserve the index and values?